# Homotopy classes of maps from three torus to unitary matrices

Tags: algebraic-topology, mathematical-physics, homotopy-theory

I want to understand the origin / justification for the eqn 4 of the following paper 
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.6126.pdf

I have three questions. It will be great if someone can help me with any or all of these.

The eqn claims to classify up to homotopy, all maps from Three torus to unitary matrices (sufficiently large). How do I arrive at such classifying functions in general ?

how do I see that homptopy classes of maps from three torus to unitary matrices are isomorphic to integers ?

How do I see that the integral in the eqn is an integer  ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I haven't looked at the paper, but I can help calculate $[\mathbb T^3, U]$ - which is $\mathbb Z^{\oplus 4}$. Perhaps you wanted $[\mathbb T^3, SU] = \mathbb Z$.

I will first give an elementary argument, then a more algebraic one that uses Bott periodicity.

**Argument 1.** First consider the special unitary group. As is discussed at [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/101228/cw-structure-on-unitary-group) there is a cell structure for $SU(n)$ having 4-skeleton $SU(2) = S^3$. Every map $\mathbb T^3 \to S^3$ is homotopic to a cellular map, which thus factors through $\mathbb T^3 /(2-\text{skeleton}) = S^3$. Since there are no 4-cells we actually have $$\mathbb Z = \pi_3(S^3) = [\mathbb T^3, SU].$$ This reasoning is pretty common, it's similar to, say, [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1165049/classification-of-all-maps-t2-to-s4-up-to-homotopy?rq=1). As for $U(n)$, one has $U(n) \simeq SU(n)\times S^1$ so $$[\mathbb T^3, U] = [\mathbb T^3, SU] \times H^1(\mathbb T^3;\mathbb Z) = [\mathbb T^3, SU] \times \mathbb Z^3.$$

We have just used that $[X, S^1] = H^1(X,\mathbb Z)$, see [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/677015/group-structure-on-pointed-homotopy-classes-x-s1?rq=1).

Here is a more algebraic argument.

**Argument 2.** From [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301402/suspension-of-a-product-tricky-homotopy-equivalence) we have $\Sigma(X\times Y) \simeq \Sigma X \vee \Sigma Y \vee \Sigma(X\wedge Y)$
Thus for $\mathbb T^3 = S^1\times \mathbb T^2$ we calculate
$$\Sigma(\mathbb T^3) \simeq S^2\vee\Sigma \mathbb T^2 \vee\Sigma^2\mathbb T^2$$

It is a common exercise that $\Sigma \mathbb T^2 \simeq S^2\vee S^2 \vee S^3$ (this must be on MSE somewhere...) thus
$$\Sigma\mathbb T^3 \simeq S^2 \vee (S^2\vee S^2 \vee S^3)\vee(S^3\vee S^3\vee S^4) = (S^2)^{\vee 3}\vee(S^3)^{\vee 3}\vee S^4$$

Now we can use Bott perioidicty again $$[\mathbb T^3, U] = [\mathbb T^3, \Omega^2U] = [\Sigma^2 \mathbb T^3, U].$$

Thus $$[\mathbb T^3, U] = \pi_3(U)^{\oplus 3} \oplus \pi_4(U)^{\oplus 3} \oplus \pi_5(U) = \mathbb Z^{\oplus 4}.$$